# How to find handle of instagram account from user hash in downloaded data

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Apologies in advance if this question is not appropriate for stackoverflow.com

I am looking through my downloaded instagram data in JSON. Within the massive zip stores my instagram direct messages under `/messages/inbox/<name>_<hash>/message_1.json`, and I am trying to find the handle of the user. However, I realised that it doesn't exist in the downloaded data.

For example, in my downloaded data there is a folder at `/messages/inbox/williamlin_q1pfmnzw9w`, which contains my conversation with https://www.instagram.com/tmwilliamlin168/. However, the handle `tmwilliamlin168` never appears in my downloaded data. So my question is how to find it?

I suspect that it might be related to the hash `q1pfmnzw9w` at the end, but I am unable to relate the hash to either the username or the user id `25569171238` (found [here](https://www.instagram.com/tmwilliamlin168/?__a=1)). An observation about the hash is that it is in the form `[0-9a-z_\-]{10}`.

Thanks for your help.